# In Etherreum Quorum, can a private contract invoke another private contract shared with a different set of participants?

Tags: quorum

Let's say I have the following four nodes

- Node A
- Node B
- Node C
- Node D

And the following three smart contracts

- Smart contract AB (private to A & B)
- Smart contract BC (private to B & C)
- Smart contract ABD (private to A, B & D)

Can either smart contract AB or BC invoke a method on smart contract ABCD as all are marked as private contracts? I know that this cannot be done from Node C as contract ABD does not exist on node C. But can this work from nodes A or B?